# Ninject binding with multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, ninject

I have a controller like this:

```
public class Controller
{
    public TokenService _service;

    [Inject]
    public Controller(TokenService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

With TokenService looking like this:

```
public class TokenService: IInterface1, IInterface2 {}
```

How do I bind this in Ninject? I would have thought I needed to change the TokenService constructor parameter in the Controller to be one of those 2 interfaces.

The reason I have 2 interfaces is because TokenService is used for DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: It's a different problem, but see also http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/30/new-features-and-changes-of-ninject-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't need to bind it at all, because as far as I know, Ninject automatically binds all concrete types to themselves.

If this is not the case, just do it yourself:

```
kernel.Bind<TokenService>().ToSelf();
```

Comment: Is this bad practice for testing purposes?

Comment: The self binding? Or that you use a concrete type as a dependency in `Controller`?

Comment: Concrete type as a dependency

Comment: It violates the principle that states you should program against abstractions, yes. It might be a good idea, to extract an interface that contains that part of the TokenService class that is needed by the Controller.

Comment: So basically add a 3rd interface then pass that into the controller?

Comment: If this makes sense in your context, yes.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/InterfacesAreNotAbstractions.aspx